# Why I should tap 3 times (triple click) on the touchpad to launch applications and open folders in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.10, touchpad

The basic "double click" functionality to open folders and launch applications is not working properly using the touchpad, although it works fine using a mouse.
Is this a problem with Nautilus?
Is this a bug in Ubuntu 17.10? Can I fix it?
I have a HP 15-bs037ne.